# query with options in pydatalab to specify a default dataset

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

is there any possibility to specify a default dataset id in the [google.datalab.bigquery](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/google.datalab.bigquery.html#google.datalab.bigquery.Query) module while querying? I do not want to specify the whole project_id+dataset_id+table_id, write only the table_id in queries and then add the other ones manually.

Some colleagues do have the possibility in PHP, I'll write more if I reach them out for further information.

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to specify the dataset?

Comment: The reason is on the one hand comfort and on the other hand that I want to change that by config later but not change the query itself (e.g. for change between staging/production). 

So I want to specify it, but I don't want to specify it in the query itself, rather in some config files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious how your colleagues are doing it in PHP, because AFAIK you **always** need to specify at a minimum the dataset and the table in a query. However, you may omit the project id if you wish, and and the default will be used (whatever you have set it to).

Comment: They probably used the option to pass to the query mentioned as [default dataset in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) somewhat. But I wasn't able to figure out how to to this with the pydatalab package.

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to create a query job configuration and set the default dataset and not specify it in the SQL query itself, is that right?